# Android Studio error with capacitor-cordova-plugins

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

Hello i am trying to test my Capacitor 3 app with Android Studio and i am getting an error  about the cordova plugins that i am using. I tried everything i found online but i am still getting the error.

Delete `./android` folder
`npm install @capacitor/android`
then add android again `npx cap add android` finally sync `npx cap sync`

still error

tried to sync file with Gradle in Android Studio **File** and **Sync Project with Gradle Files**

still error

any help

the error i am getting is

```
cannot find symbol
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPluginPathHandler;
                         ^
  symbol:   class CordovaPluginPathHandler
  location: package org.apache.cordova
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the `cordovaAndroidVersion` variable in `variables.gradle` to `cordovaAndroidVersion = '10.1.1'`

Or downgrade `cordova-plugin-file` to 6.0.2

Comment: The error is gone now. But i can deploy on tablet. It opens with Capacitor logo -it should be my project's logo- and it goes off. Any hint?

Comment: do you see any error on logcat?

Comment: Supplied proguard configuration file name is unsupported. Valid values are: [proguard-android-optimize.txt, proguard-defaults.txt, proguard-android.txt]. but the thing is that it's doesn't get the resources icons  and anytime i get a new error. I dont know what to do. Anyway i ll try something and i'll get back to you. Thanks guys.

Comment: I've never seen that error, sorry.

Comment: For future reference if you get an error about capacitor-cordova-plugins do as Julio suggested above